# Pandas: group by column and count repetitions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm having some problems obtaining a dataframe from another one.

Summarizing, I have this dataframe:

```
Word | ... | ... | Code
w1   | ... | ... | 1234
w1   | ... | ... | 2345
...
w1  | ... | ... | 5678
w2  | ... | ... | 5678
w2  | ... | ... | 1234
...
wXX  | ... | ... | YYYY
```

I want to obtain a new dataframe from this one that looks like:

```
Code |  w1 |  w2 |  w3 ...
1234 | #w1 | #w2 | #w3 ...
2345 | #w1 | #w2 | #w3 ...
```

That is, a new df whose indices are the codes and whose columns are labeled by each word. In each row I want to count how many times a word have a determined code. Is there any way to do it? I've been trying using groupby but I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc=len`:

```
print (df)
  Word  Code
0   w1  1234
1   w1  2345
2   w1  5678
3   w2  5678
4   w2  1234

df = df.pivot_table(index='Code', columns='Word', aggfunc=len)
print (df)
Word   w1   w2
Code          
1234  1.0  1.0
2345  1.0  NaN
5678  1.0  1.0
```

If need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and remove column name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Code', columns='Word', aggfunc=len)
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   Code   w1   w2
0  1234  1.0  1.0
1  2345  1.0  NaN
2  5678  1.0  1.0
```

If need replace `NaN` to `0`, add parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Code', columns='Word', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print (df)
   Code  w1  w2
0  1234   1   1
1  2345   1   0
2  5678   1   1
```